# How do I evaluate this summation series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, exponentiation, summation-method

I came across this problem and I couldn't solve it

$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{6^r}{(3^r-2^r)(3^{r+1}-2^{r+1})}$

So when I saw the solution they wrote $6^r = 3^r(3^{r+1}-2^{r+1}) - 3^{r+1}(3^r-2^r)$ and then applying the V(r)-V(r-1) to further solve it.
I can't understand how they wrote $6^r$, I mean how did they construct it in the first place, what was the idea to form it?

And if possible is there any other elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: You should have a $-$ sign between the two products.

Comment: @Bernard Yeah, I edited it. Sorry for the mistake, and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As for construction, "take something that telescopes, and simplify the summand"...

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$T_r=\frac{6^r}{(3^r-2^r)(3^{r+1}-2^{r+1})}=\frac{3^r}{3^r-2^r}-\frac{3^{r+1}}{3^{r+1}-2^{r+1}}=F_r-F_{r+1}$$
By telescopic summation we get
$$T_r=F_r-F_{r+1}$$
$$T_1=F_1-F_2$$
$$T_2=F_2-F_3$$
$$............$$
$$T_{n-1}=F_{n-1}-F_n$$
$$T_n=F_n-F_{n+1}$$
$$\implies S_n=\sum_{r=1}^{n}T_r=F_1-F_{n+1}=3-\frac{3^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}-2^{n+1}}$$
$$\implies S_{\infty}=3-1=2$$